# Google App Engine: No module named google.api

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have installed the latest version of google cloud sdk, `google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python` on my Ubuntu PC as mentioned in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#deb) in-order to test `google-cloud-endpoints-framework` sample [app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo).

But on invoking an api request, I got the below traceback. Seems like there is a conflict between `google` package inside GAE sdk and the `google` package installed automatically to the `lib` folder because of [`google-endpoints`](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python) package.

```
$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml
INFO     2017-03-14 07:51:36,173 devappserver2.py:764] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-03-14 07:51:36,199 api_server.py:268] Starting API server at: http://localhost:44561
INFO     2017-03-14 07:51:36,213 dispatcher.py:199] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2017-03-14 07:51:36,213 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2017-03-14 07:51:45,811 module.py:806] default: "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 404 -
ERROR    2017-03-14 07:51:45,877 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/gemini/gae projects/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    import endpoints
  File "/home/gemini/gae projects/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from apiserving import *
  File "/home/gemini/gae projects/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints/apiserving.py", line 74, in <module>
    from google.api.control import client as control_client
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 1001, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.api
```

I tried creating a seperate virtualenv but the problem still exists.

Comment: This *might* help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399303/using-two-python-libraries-with-conflicting-names.

Comment: I have properly set the app_engine config file,. but I can't make it possible.. Can you file a bug regarding this?

Comment: created an issue, hope it would help..

Comment: @DanCornilescu https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/853#issuecomment-286998502

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the reply from a google guy..

> Local development with endpoints framework v2 isn't currently supported, you'll need to deploy the app.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/853

Answer (score 4):

Your error :

```
ImportError: No module named google.api
```

So you need first to install gcloud python module and **google-api-python-client** module with:

```
pip install --upgrade gcloud
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703853/how-to-use-google-speech-recognition-api-in-python/38788928#38788928)

Comment: Do you able to test endpoints v2 API locally? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/main.py

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with other Google packages in my `lib` directory.
I solved/monkey patched it using the following code in my `appengine_config.py` file:

```
import sys
import os
import google
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
lib_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "<relative path to lib dir>"
google.__path__.append(os.path.join(lib_directory, 'google'))
logging.info("importing lib %s" % (lib_directory))
vendor.add(lib_directory)
```