# Python app engine SDK: import error google.appengine.ext.remote_api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am currently using appengine (standard environment) and datastore, we also have some CRON scripts running on our local servers that connect remotely to datastore and insert daily updates.

The main problem I am facing is that currently the new SDK:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download

After running the specified commands:

`gcloud components install app-engine-python`

The following script still does not work:

```
try:
    import dev_appserver
    dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
except ImportError:
    pass

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
PROJECT_ID = "lipexdb-test"
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth(
    '{}.appspot.com'.format(PROJECT_ID),
    '/_ah/remote_api/') #notasecret
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

try:
    from google.cloud import bigquery as bq
except Exception, e:
    print "Cannot import bigquery"
    print e
```

Failing with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testenv.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext.remote_api
```

I used to be able to make it work using the "Original App engine SDK for python" (available on the same link above) but that causes a few issues (mainly two "google" libraries in the path which then conflicts with all `google.cloud.` packages).

So does the new App engine SDK does not have the python packages? And how can I make them work along google.cloud (bigquery/pubsub) packages?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399303/using-two-python-libraries-with-conflicting-names

Comment: I have executed a snippet of your code and it works for me. What happens if you just execute `from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub`?