# How to import modules when modules have same folder names,

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-python

I'm facing an issue where `google.appengine` and `google.cloud` python modules are under different directories named `google`

Their following paths are as below:

`1st Path:` C:\Users\MohammedT\Desktop\dsapp\sitepackages\dev\google_appengine

```
api_server.py
appcfg.py
backends_conversion.py
BUGS
bulkloader.py
bulkload_client.py
demos
dev_appserver.py
download_appstats.py
endpointscfg.py
gen_protorpc.py
google    --> Directory 1 where appengine module resides
lib
LICENSE
new_project_template
php
php_cli.py
README
RELEASE_NOTES
remote_api_shell.py
run_tests.py
```

`2nd Path:` C:\Users\MohammedT\Desktop\datastore\dsenv\Lib\site-packages

```
enum
enum34-1.1.6.dist-info
future
future-0.16.0.dist-info
futures-3.2.0.dist-info
gapic_google_cloud_datastore_v1-0.15.3-py2.7-nspkg.pth
gapic_google_cloud_datastore_v1-0.15.3.dist-info
gapic_google_cloud_error_reporting_v1beta1-0.15.3-py2.7-nspkg.pth
gapic_google_cloud_error_reporting_v1beta1-0.15.3.dist-info
gapic_google_cloud_logging_v2-0.91.3-py2.7-nspkg.pth
gapic_google_cloud_logging_v2-0.91.3.dist-info
google    ------------> Directory 2 where other other modules resides
googleapiclient
googleapis_common_protos-1.5.3-py2.7-nspkg.pth
googleapis_common_protos-1.5.3.dist-info
google_api_core-0.1.3-py3.6-nspkg.pth
google_api_core-0.1.3.dist-info
google_api_python_client-1.6.4.dist-info
```

Can I achieve this without moving them to a common directory?

I have set the python path to point at both of these directories. I'm currently able to import from Directory 2 but cannot import from Directory 1

Comment: If this is all part of a package you are developing, you may want to review the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for some guidance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Two Python Libraries with Conflicting Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399303/using-two-python-libraries-with-conflicting-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load each module from its path.  In Python 2 use:

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()
```

additional detail in this lovely answer: 
[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)